# Generated Sigma-algebra example

Tags: measure-theory

I know that a sigma algebra generated by a subset a, $\sigma(a) = \{\emptyset,a,a^c,E\}$.

But what about $\sigma({a,b})$? Would it be $\{\emptyset,a,a^c, b, b^c,E\}$?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is, in particular, closed under finite intersections and unions. Your claimed example is not.

Comment: You are missing, potentially, $a\cap b$, $a\triangle b$, $a-b$, $b-a$, $(a-b)\cup b^c$, and lots more...

Comment: thanks, so the only way to find \sigma({a,b}) is to check $a\cap b$...?

Comment: @Thomas: I don't understand what you mean by "check $a\cap b$". Note that each of the "basic 4" sets will be in your $\sigma$-algebra: $a\cap b$, $a-b$, $b-a$, $a^c\cap b^c$ (these correspond to the four collections in the most general situation: things in both $a$ and $b$; in $a$ but not in $b$; in $b$ but not in $a$; and neither $a$ nor $b$. Then you have all possible unions of these four regions (which gives 16 possibilities). If $a\subseteq b$, $a\subseteq b^c$, $b\subseteq a$, or $b\subseteq a^c$, then some of these possibilities are repeats, but in general, you may need all of them.

Comment: $\sigma(\{a\})$ generally has 4 elements; $\sigma(\{a,b\})$ generally has 16 elements.

Comment: Thanks arturo, sorry for not making it clear. I meant checking as in seeing if they are repeats and which are not repeats.

Comment: And more generally, if you start with $n$ sets, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by those $n$ sets will generally have $2^{2^n}$ elements, always has at most that many, and you can always find an example where it has exactly that many elements.

Comment: thanks again. So i take it that its generally not practical to list out all the elements/construct the elements for large sets? Are there any applications/examples where we would need to?

Comment: @Thomas: Depends on what you mean. It is relatively easy to list all the $2^{2^n}$ possibilities. I don't know about any particular applications or examples, though.

Comment: hmmm, okay. Thanks for all your help again!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to describe the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite partition $\{A_1,\dots,A_N\}$ of $\Omega$: it consists of the sets $\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j$, where $j\subset [N]$.

In this particular case, consider $A_1=A\cap B$, $A_2=A^c\cap B$, $A_3:=A\cap B^c$, $A_4:=A^c\cap B^c$. These sets form a partition of $\Omega$.

Of course, we can describe in the same way the $\sigma$-algebra generated by [a finite collection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319430/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set/319831#319831) $S_1,\dots,S_n$.